# When did Darth Vader get his red lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

Between Episodes III and IV, when and how did Darth Vader obtain/construct his red lightsaber?

Comment: He gets it on Mustafar, according to the PS2 Revenge of the Sith game. Palpatine gives it to him when he lands to pick him up, after Anakin kills Obi-Wan.

Comment: @GhotiandChips And that game was sanctioned by LucasFilm? Doesn't make any sense as there is an obvious conflict with even pre-Disney canon.

Comment: @Ghoti, clearly the red saber exists before the scene in IV where vader and kenobi duel.

Comment: @Octopus I think you mis-read my comment: it clearly reads **Revenge of the Sith**.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET No, it's not canon, as it is an alternate ending for the game (it is more like fanfiction from the writers of the game). That being said, it does lend credence to the idea that Palpatine already had the lightsaber ready for him, since Revenge of the Sith was being made alongside the production of the film, there was a lot of cross-pollination with the movie production team, including early drafts of scripts, character concepts (that got cut from the movie), and indeed alternate versions. It was just a bit of trivia I wanted to add as a comment.

Comment: @GhotiandChips: But you write "after Anakin kills Obi-Wan". Anakin (Vader) doesn't kill Obi-Wan until Episode IV, at which point Vader has long had his red saber.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Anakin *does* kill Obi-Wan in *Revenge of the Sith* PS2 game :) And that's where you see Palpatine giving him the red saber, at Mustafar. I never mentioned or referenced Episode IV, that was all you.

Comment: @GhotiandChips: Oh, you're talking about some kind of a non-canon alternate ending? You should mention that. Otherwise, when you say "Anakin kills Obi-Wan", it will be taken for granted (not only by me, as the confusion in the comments shows) you mean the respective event from Episode IV (which, for all I know as I haven't played the *Revenge of the Sith* PS2 game, might well be shown in that game in some sort of an epilogue).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper "You should mention that" >I would, if I hadn't already

Comment: *Obviously*, he got the red lightsaber at the same time he got the edgy-badass mask/hood. Both are part of the *"Sith starter kit"*.

Comment: @xDaizu Vader only got the uniform because by the time he pledged to the KickStarter the BadassSith pledge was already full.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

#### Vader built his lightsaber within five years of his fall to the dark side

Cross-referencing Wookieepedia's [timeline of canon media](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Timeline_of_canon_media) and [article on Anakin Skywalker](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker), I believe the canon source which first depicts Vader after his fall to the dark side in Episode III is the novel [*Lords of the Sith*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Lords_of_the_Sith). The events of that novel occurred five years after Episode III, and the novel does mention that his lightsaber is red:

> The red line of Vader’s lightsaber flashed, deflecting the shots back at the Twi’lek, putting a dark hole in his chest and another in his face.
>
> <sub>**p. 108**</sub>

No canon source appears to describe *how* he built it (or if it was given to him), but presumably he built it just as he built his lightsaber as a Jedi.

Answer (score 44):

In Episode III, *Revenge of the Sith*, Anakin had a blue lightsaber.

In Episode IV, *A New Hope*, he has a red lightsaber.

Therefore, he acquired it in the 19 years between those two.

As Wookieepedia says [here](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Vader%27s_lightsaber):

> Darth Vader's lightsaber was the personal lightsaber of Darth Vader, a Sith Lord. He built the weapon some time after his fall to the Dark side of the Force at the end of the Clone Wars. It replaced the one he lost during his duel with Obi-Wan Kenobi on Mustafar.

It is common for Force Users to build their own lightsabers; for example, Luke's new one in Episode VI.

---

In [Legends](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Vader%27s_lightsaber/Legends), we have something more concrete. In [*Dark Lord: The Rise of Darth Vader*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Lord:_The_Rise_of_Darth_Vader), which takes place directly after episode three, Vader creates his lightsaber.  he is seen here with the new lightsaber in Chapter 9:

> In his quarters aboard the capital ship now under his personal command, Darth Vader, gloved and
>   artificial right hand clamped on the hilt of his new lightsaber, knelt before a larger-than-life hologram of
>   Emperor Palpatine.

And in Chapter 13:

> Sidious had provided the synthcrystal responsible for the crimson blade, along with his own lightsaber
>   to serve as a model. Vader, though, had no fondness for antiques, and while he could appreciate the
>   handiwork that had gone into fashioning the inlaid, gently curved hilt of Sidious's lightsaber, he preferred a
>   weapon with more ballast

So yes, he made the lightsaber in 19 BBY, directly after Episode III, in Legends.

Comment: So according to your answer, the answer is "we don't really know, we just have a massive time span where it could have happened"?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Yes.

Comment: Also I haven't watched any of the animated series, did he have it in any of them?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder  -  he has it in *Rebels*, which is set between the trilogies.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I couldn't remember the name of it, at least that narrows down the time window!

Comment: @TheLethalCoder "massive span"? I wouldn't expect a Jedi or Sith Lord to be without a lightsaber for 1 month, not 19 years. I'd expect he made one as soon as he recovered.

Comment: I've accepted the other answer because it gives a closer timespan for when the saber was created with canon sources. But I have upvoted yours :)

Comment: @TheLethalCoder All right, thanks.

Comment: It's been multiple decades, and I still haven't built _my_ lightsaber yet . . .

Answer (score 16):

**In Legends, less than a month.**

[Bol Chatak](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bol_Chatak) was one of the few Jedi that managed to escape Order 66. She was killed on [Murkhana](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Murkhana/Legends) in a lightsaber duel with Vader, by which point he had his red saber. This took place less than one month after the events of Episode III.

**In Disney Canon, definitely within 5 years, possibly within a month**

As Null says, the earliest canon reference to Vader's saber is *Lords of the Sith*, which takes place 5 years after Episode III ends, though it is apparently mentioned in the novel *Tarkin* that Vader performed an execution for the Emperor on the planet Murkhana, so the event that occurred in Legends may still be true. This cannot be proven definitively, however, because we aren't given any details. I think it would be safe to assume that Vader had a red lightsaber before going on *any* missions, though.

Comment: According to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_Legends_media) the [Purge series](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Purge) predates *Dark Lord: The Rise of Darth Vader* in which Bol Chatak was killed. In *Purge*, Darth Vader already had his red lightsaber and killed a group of Jedi.

Comment: Good find, though while that's true, it still doesn't change the answer, as technically we can't really get any more accurate than "Less than a month".

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: he probably built it very early on. Perhaps as early as just prior to his final scene in RotS. (The one with Tarkin & the Death Star under construction in the background.)

Due to the way the scene is shot and edited it's not possible for it to be visible on screen if it is there, but [the prop was certainly made for the movie](https://youtu.be/L9HmbPJarBA?t=5m28s) and it's shown up in [promotional photos of Hayden in the armor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/File:SidiousVaderPromo.JPG), so it seems reasonably likely it was part of his costume for that last scene.

As to when that scene takes place: it's tough to say exactly. That final montage seems to cover at least a few days, if not weeks. Assuming one is to take the order the scenes are presented as the literal chronological order of events (which may not actually be the case) then this scene falls right between Padme's funeral and Bail returning home to Alderaan with baby Leia.

The scene is somewhat revisited in the *Rogue One* tie-in novel [*Catalyst*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Catalyst), albeit from Krennic's perspective and though it doesn't give any more clues than the movie, the context of what's being said certainly gives the impression this is still a matter of days--a week at the outside--after Order 66. Indeed the Emperor is said to still be recovering from his encounter with Windu.

Mind you, even if they didn't end up using it in that scene, it still seems likely Vader would have built a new one ASAP. At this point he would have built at least three others as Anakin so he certainly knows what he's doing. Resources shouldn't be a problem as *Catalyst* depicts the Empire is suddenly flush with spare kyber crystals in the wake of the Temple massacre. (See the [*Ahsoka*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ahsoka_(novel)) novel for how a reclaimed Jedi kyber can be turned into a red blade.)

Answer (score 2):

In canon, Vader secured his lightsaber from a Jedi called [Kirik Infil'a](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kirak_Infil%27a), a Jedi Master who had escaped Order 66 and was ultimately killed by Vader on a moon called Al'Doleem. The story was depicted in the canon storybook [*Star Wars: Galactic Adventures*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Galactic_Adventures).

> While Infil’a desperately tried to repair the damage and save the city, Vader
> struck the winning blow, using the Force to steal the Jedi’s lightsaber as Infil’a fell
> into the crashing waves.
>
> Darth Vader returned to his new teacher, lightsaber in hand.
> Darth Sidious was pleased with his young apprentice.
> The Sith had defeated Infil’a, and he had used the dark side of the Force to turn
> the Jedi’s green saber a deep red.
> Darth Vader was ready to complete his training as a Sith at Sidious’s side.
> Together they would become more powerful than anyone could imagine.

[image]

Comment: You can read more about it and see it drawn in the first volume of the canon comics [Darth Vader: Dark Lord of the Sith - Imperial Machinek](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Vader:_Dark_Lord_of_the_Sith_Vol._1_%E2%80%94_Imperial_Machine)

Comment: @karaelfte - Indeed. I'm still working up a slightly longer answer.

Answer (score 1):

### First ever explanation (but ambiguously canon in Legends)

The other answers explain the Legends and Disney canon explanations, but I'd also like to throw out the first ever explanation (even if it was ambiguously canon even at the time), which was in the [*Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith* video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_%E2%80%93_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(video_game)). This came out on May 4, 2005 which was released 11 days before the movie.

In an alternate ending, Anakin kills Obi-Wan Kenobi in their duel. Emperor Palpatine arrives on Mustafar and hands him a new red lightsaber, then Anakin kills him with it.

As we can see, the Emperor already had the red lightsaber ready to give to Vader. It stands to reason that Palpatine gave it to Vader as soon as he had recovered enough to use it.

Granted, this relies on whether Palpatine having the lightsaber is still C-canon (according to the Legends classifications system) despite the ending itself being non-canon.