# Who makes all the other lightsabers?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, lightsaber

According to [this no-longer-canon answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/26852/75000) you don't *have* to be a Force user to build a Lightsaber, and [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/26829/75000) states that there is no outside company that builds them, so **who's in charge of creating all the training sabers, pikes, and other weaponry**?

There's no mention of the Jedi Temple Guards making their own weapons either on their [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Temple_Guard/Legends) or [databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/jedi-temple-guard) pages, but they must come from somewhere. Same with [training sabers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Training_lightsaber/Legends).

My thought is that there's a group of retired or artisan Jedi who spend their time producing or replacing things for the armory. Kinda like how older earthlings take up wood carving.

Is anything related to this ever mentioned?

Comment: Well, that answer isn’t entirely correct anymore, being based on old canon (pre-Disney). Current evidence suggests that not only is the Force very close to necessary to align lightsaber crystals properly, but that without the Force, it would be very difficult to attune to the kyber crystal (which leads to some of the utility of lightsabers). *On the other hand*, information from *Rebels* suggests that even non-Force-sensitives may have enough of a connection to the Force (it *is* present in everyone to some extent) to benefit from a lightsaber kyber crystal to some extent.

Comment: Don't really care about canon. Make whatever connections you need to. Sorry if that makes it too broad.

Comment: I believe they are bought from Ollivanders down Diagon Alley.

Comment: @Peter  -  from comments under [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151256/when-did-darth-vader-get-his-red-lightsaber/): https://imgur.com/a/9T74R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the excellent, but alas no longer canon, [Jedi Path - A Manual for Students of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_(real-life_book)) we learn that there are classes at the Jedi Temple devoted to the assembly, repair and maintenance of lightsabers. This would imply that the students themselves are responsible for the general upkeep of the Temple's stock of Training Lightsabers, under the supervision of their trainers.

Additionally, it notes that the Training Lightsabers are of a *standard* design, implying that they're constructed in bulk. Again, we can assume that the Jedi maintain a small stock of spare kyber crystals and standardised lightsaber parts to repair and replace any sabers that get scrapped.

> A training saber consists of a hilt and an activation stud that, when
>   pressed, extends the blade. The size of the hilt and the length of the
>   blade are variable, based on the combatant’s age and size. Inside the
>   hilt is a crystal, lens, and emitter matrix to focus the blade, and a
>   power cell to energize it. **In another class you will learn to
>   disassemble and reassemble this saber, but in this class you will
>   simply learn how to use it.**

There's mention of a Lightsaber crafting facility within the Temple grounds in the excellent [Complete Locations](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Complete_Locations_(2016)) factbook.

[image]

Comment: Bearing in mind that the Jedi act like a monastic religious order, my gut instinct is that whenever a Jedi Master has time on their hands, they trail down to the "*to do list*" board and spent a few hours doing whatever tasks need doing around the Temple, whether it's fixing a broken door or cleaning blood off of the training room floor.

Comment: That makes sense

Answer (score 3):

In current canon (films), we see a couple of instances of light sabers being handed down, from Jedi to Padawan.

> *Obi Wan Kenobi, Ep 4:* I have something here for you. Your father wanted you to have this when you were old enough, but your uncle wouldn't allow it. He feared you might follow old Obi-Wan on some damn fool idealistic crusade like your father did.

and

> *Maz Kanata, Ep 7: [to Rey]* That lightsaber was Luke's. And his father's before him. And now, it calls to you.

Would it be safe to assume, then, that the Jedi have a long tradition of doing this? If so, it could mean that some sabers are hundreds if not thousands of years old.

Comment: This is an excellent point. Perhaps the Jedi temple guard sabers, say, have been handed down from a group of original temple guards.

Comment: I'm not asking about **actual** Lightsabers, which are usually built be the individual wielder. I seriously doubt that there's any training saber that's more than 5 or 10 years old.

Comment: @Adamant Perhaps, but who built them originally? Who tends to their upkeep? True that they're Lightsaber resistant, but can they still bend? Chip? Crack? Get lost or stolen?

Comment: This answer could be improved by being a bit more specific where you the lightsabers being handed down.

Comment: Considering that both quotes are talking about the same lightsaber, which is really a plot device for the stories it's involved in, I'm not sure we can draw that conclusion to apply generally like this.

Comment: Additionally, both instances occurred when the Jedi Order was destroyed, and therefore shouldn't be considered standard.